# E: Unable to correct probl..., you have held broken packages. Error while upgrading & installing Steam

Tags: debian, packages, steam, dependencies, parrot-os

I'm using **Parrot** *Electro Ara (Debian-Mate)*

I'm having an error while trying to **upgrade** my system (`sudo apt upgrade`):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  azure-cli ruby-mini-portile2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  azure-cli ruby-mini-portile2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I tried everything, *autoremove, purge, safe-upgrade*, but still can't get rid of it to make a clean upgrade.

Also having the same problem when installing **Steam**:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libvulkan1:i386 (>= 1.2.131.2) but it is not going to be installed
 steam-libs-i386:i386 : Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libudev0:i386 but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installable
                        Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this? I've tried installing the packages manually but they are in the latest version, also tried to change the Steam Architecture using `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` but nothing seems to work.

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
libdrm.so.2
libdrm.so.2
libdrm.so.2
```

Hope I'm giving enough details and if there's something wrong in my question let me know, I just installed parrot from scratch therefore there shouldn't be any problem.

Tried to search all over stack exchange about this but there are no answers.